# Troubleshoot HTTP 403 from API Gateway - Amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have an api gateway with api key.
I am trying to test my api using Advanced Rest Client but it doesn't work.

[image]

Can you help me to understand what I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Have you given a look at https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-authentication-token-errors/?

Comment: You have to provide all settings of your API gateway.

Comment: Is this API actually configured requiring an API key?  This error seems to suggest some other mechanism in place like an IAM authorizer.